# Avoiding repeated outbound calls from twilio python program

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

This is my python script that I run from command line.It makes a call to the 10_DIGIT_NO.If I dont answer the call it repeatedly makes calls.The twiml was generated via https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/my/create?type=callme. How to avoid this??
I want the call to be made just once irrespective of it being received or not.

Thanks

```
# Download the library from twilio.com/docs/libraries
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

    # Get these credentials from http://twilio.com/user/account
    account_sid = "xyz"
    auth_token = "abc"
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

    # Make the call 
    call = client.calls.create(to="10_DIGIT_NO",  # Any phone number
                               from_="MY_TWILIO_NO", # Must be a valid Twilio number
                               url="XML_FILE_PATH")
    print call.sid
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. It looks like we'll need to dig into your account a bit to diagnose this properly - I would recommend e-mailing help@twilio.com so that we can help you find a solution!